# Problem in Understanding Recursion - Java

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I got the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950085/permutations-of-a-string) question, I ran it in Eclipse and the code was fine, but I confused myself in how the recursion order goes internally.

```
public class Permute {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        String text = bufReader.readLine();
        shuffle("", text);
    }

    public static void shuffle(String dummy, String input) {
        if (input.length() <= 1)
            System.out.println(dummy + input);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                input = input.substring(i, i + 1) + input.substring(0, i)
                        + input.substring(i + 1);
                shuffle(dummy + input.substring(0, 1), input.substring(1));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found difficulty in understanding recursion in the `for` loop of `Shuffle`. Any pointers in decoding the recursion steps?

**EDIT** : Okay this is my understanding, say suppose my input is ABC and when i run in the first loop , i get dummy = A and input = BC, so the immediate step would be to go down the recursion for input = BC and dummy = A and then come back to iterate i for the initial input ?

Comment: Trace the calls to shuffle along with actual arguments, and you will underatand.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion (it may help you to read that first)

Comment: @z7sg : No i'm good in recursion i only want to make sure am thinking right

Comment: to remind an old joke: to understand recursion you must first understand recursion :)

Comment: @SuperMan OK I misunderstood.  Perhaps this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614665/problem-in-understanding-recursion-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global counter:

```
static int depth = 0; /* calling depth of the recursive method */
```

Add as the first line of `shuffle`:

```
System.out.printf("%" + depth++ + "s call dummy='%s' input='%s'\n", "", dummy, input);
```

Add as the last line of `shuffle`:

```
System.out.printf("%" + --depth + "s return\n", "");
```

Run the program. Now you can see what happens.

Comment: That's weird. Any details on the error message? I tested it with Sun JDK 1.6.0_20, and it worked.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failMismatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkBadFlags(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkGeneral(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)

Comment: Ah, ok, I only tested the code with depth==13. so just initialize depth to 1, and it should work. The zero has a special meaning in this context, any other number will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as dividing the job in steps. Your `shuffle` function takes two arguments, `dummy` for the part of the string that is already shuffled, and `input` for the part of the string that still has to be shuffled.

At every step, you shuffle the first character of `input`:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            input = input.substring(i, i + 1) + input.substring(0, i)
                    + input.substring(i + 1);
```

and then, recursively apply the algorhythm, with the part already shuffled being a character longer:

```
            shuffle(dummy + input.substring(0, 1), input.substring(1));
```

Until there is nothing more to shuffle:

```
    if (input.length() <= 1)
        System.out.println(dummy + input);
```

Comment: Yes i was doing this way. So i come back to increment i for the initial input right ?

Comment: @SuperMan: think of the recursive call as a black box that does the algorhythm on an input of length - 1. It's similar to thinking of mathemathical induction, if you know about that.

Answer (score 1):

It exhaustively shuffles the input by the inputs length, recursively. So once each recursion has shuffled the string by the `i'th` term, it returns.

This would be an n-squared complexity algorithm in big-O notation.

The shuffling is tricky to work out without a debugger ;)